# (SQL) Want to know request numbers that exist with one value but not another

Tags: sql

I'm querying a single table that has a column (SignatureDocumentType) with two possible outcomes 'PreliminaryTestReport' and 'FinalTestReport'. When either exists for a single RequestID a new row is created. I want to know all RequestIDs where 'PreliminaryTestReport' exists but 'FinalTestReport' doesn't exist for the same RequestID.

When I run the below I return no values and I know there is at least 1 that fits the criteria

```
select RequestID from RequestDocumentSignature 
where not exists (select RequestID from RequestDocumentSignature where SignatureDocumentType = 'FinalTestReport') and 
exists (select RequestID from RequestDocumentSignature where SignatureDocumentType = 'PreliminaryTestReport')
group by RequestID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for the second `exists`. You can apply where for the table (outer query) itself.

Also, don't forget to filter inner `exists` data by `RequestID`.

Here is query, that should work for you:

```sql
select
    DISTINCT RequestID
from
    RequestDocumentSignature r1
where
    not exists (
        select
            1
        from
            RequestDocumentSignature r2
        where
            r2.SignatureDocumentType = 'FinalTestReport'
            and r2.RequestID = r1.RequestID
    )
    and r1.SignatureDocumentType = 'PreliminaryTestReport'
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: @jarlh, oops, left from original query in question. Thank you.